# Video not saved in external storage Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

I'm using one library just to trim picked video from gallery and upload on server that same trimmed video. Video is trimmed and saved to external storage. But issue appears on Android Oreo there is no video just an empty (unplayable) file when I check inside my created folder.

Because this works on all below APIs beside API 26 my first thought is that issue is caused by `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. So here is explanation how I'm asking for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

When app loads I ask for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` after allowing that permission when user wants to open up gallery I'm checking is API 26 or later and asking for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
   if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "App doesn't have permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
       }
     dialog.dismiss();
     makeTransaction(R.id.activityMainContainer, new LoadVideosFragment());

  }
```

Inside `onRequestPermissionsResult` I'm checking is `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` allowed:

```
else if (requestCode == 2 && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("Permission", "Granted");
    }
```

And `Granted` is printed out in Logcat.

My second thought was that maybe some of libraries have inside manifest `maxSdkVersion` in `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` set to `18` so I checked in `Merged Manifest` and there is none.

Code for creating `File`:

```
public static File createNewFile(String fileName) {
    String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/funnyvideos/";
    File dir = new File(rootPath);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    File file;
    file = new File(rootPath, fileName + ".mp4");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return file;
}
```

Does anyone know what might cause this issue? Thanks

Comment: By external storage, do you mean SD Card?

Comment: @UmangBurman thanks for response my I ask why?

Comment: "when I check inside my created folder" -- how exactly are you doing this?

Comment: @CommonsWare code updated

Comment: That wasn't what I was asking. How exactly are you checking inside the created folder?

Comment: @CommonsWare From the phone or simulator: Files -> funny videos -> and all videos which are trimmed.

Comment: Try checking via Android Studio's Device File Explorer. If that looks OK, then perhaps you are indexing that file in the `MediaStore` before the contents are written out.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay thanks I will check. The thing is it doesn't work on Oreo app is tested on many APIs like: 18, 21, 24, 25 but issue is only related to Oreo.

Comment: If you are storing the files inside a SD card then you need special permission from it via the Document Tree.. Do you know about it?